# Backbone events not catching click on div

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the next html structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom></div>
</div>
```

I have the next event set in a Backbone View:

```
className: 'wrapper',
events: { 
    'click .wrapper' : 'click_handler'
},
click_handler: function(event) {
    console.log("click handled")
}
```

This code doesn't trigger the click event when the wrapper is clicked but if I will change the click selector to the ".top" or ".bottom" the click will be triggered.

What am I doing wrong ? is it something to do with Capture/Bubble?

Comment: Show you entire view code. It's likely the top-level `div` is the view's `el`, so the event handler's selector won't match the `wrapper` class.

Comment: @DavidSulc, its the top level div in the el

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `div.wrapper` your view's $el?  `'click .wrapper'` indicates a delegating event handler, which means it will only trigger for decendents of your view's $el that have the `.wrapper` class.

[jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for `.on` describes event delegation.

**Edit**

Dropping the `.wrapper` from your events hash may give you the behavior you're looking for.  In other words:

```
className: 'wrapper',
events: { 
    'click' : 'click_handler'
},
click_handler: function(event) {
    console.log("click handled")
}
```

Comment: div.wrapper is my view's $el, how do I catch a click on it ?

Comment: Drop the `.wrapper` from the events hash.